# Assigning specific indices given by X,Y vectors to some number MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, vectorization

I'm really missing some very basic stuff here,

**Problem:**
I have a 2D matrix say

```
A =   8     1     6
      3     5     7
      4     9     2
```

Now i have some X and Y index as vectors

```
X = [1 2 3]
Y = [1 2 3]
```

Now i want `(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)` of `A` to be assigned some value say `1`

**Expected output:**

```
out =   1     1     6
        3     1     7
        4     9     1
```

Comment: I guess i figured it out `sub2ind`

Comment: @rayryeng I fear if i delete too many questions, my account might be deleted, instead if you could write an answer, i'll accept it.. if you don't mind :)

Comment: Oh :) Sure.  Of course I will.

Comment: I've written an answer.  I also wrote an alternative method as there's more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method would be to use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to create linear column-major indices to set the locations referenced by these indices to 1.  Assuming that `X` are your rows and `Y` are your columns (it's hard to tell because the matrix and locations are symmetric):

```
A(sub2ind(size(A), X, Y)) = 1;
```

Another method is to create a [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix, convert this to a `logical` matrix, and use this to index into `A` to set the corresponding locations that are `logical` `true` to 1:

```
B = logical(sparse(X, Y, 1, size(A,1), size(A,2)));
A(B) = 1;
```

Comment: Thumbs up for alternate answer :)

Comment: @SanthanSalai - Thanks :)  It depends on my mood.  Sometimes I like `sparse` and other times I like using `sub2ind`.... I might as well show you both!